Nmap scan from multiple interfaces and multiple IPs
I have a linux machine with multiple network interfaces (and sub interfaces) with different IP address for each one.
Is it possible to have a single Nmap scan of a single target that will outbound from these multiple interfaces (multiple IPs) concurrently?
For example, I want that a tcpdump output will look something like this:
07:03:18.385785 eth0  Out IP 1.2.3.4.55316 > 1.1.1.1.19118: Flags [S], seq 2851822718, win 1024, options [mss 1460], length 0
07:03:18.385836 eth0:0  Out IP 1.2.3.5.55317 > 1.1.1.1.3053: Flags [S], seq 2851822718, win 1024, options [mss 1460], length 0
07:03:18.385880 eth0  Out IP 1.2.3.4.55316 > 1.1.1.1.14650: Flags [S], seq 2851822718, win 1024, options [mss 1460], length 0
07:03:18.385917 eth0:1  Out IP 1.2.3.6.55318 > 1.1.1.1.59553: Flags [S], seq 2851822718, win 1024, options [mss 1460], length 0

In the above example I scan 1.1.1.1 from several IPs: 1.2.3.4 (eth0), 1.2.3.5 (eth0:0), 1.2.3.6 (eth0:1)
Thank you!

I don't see any security aspect in the question "single nmap run" vs. "multiple nmap runs". But, you can only give a single interface and a single source IP as arguments, which means that you need multiple runs if you want to vary with interface and source IP.

@SteffenUllrich But I want to scan the same target from multiple interfaces. Is it possible?

Please have a look at the documentation and look for "interface". It's all written there if you manage to look at the right place.

I am familiar with the manual of Nmap, but there is no option for put multiple interfaces. @SteffenUllrich

See my first comment which clearly states: "... which means that you need multiple runs if you want to vary with interface and source IP."
